# Removing escape codes from a specific cell in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-science

I'm trying to remove escape codes that are scattered throughout this one cell in my pandas column. I need to execute code to the whole column but that one cell is hindering that for all.

The code to call specific cell looks like so;
 `df.topics[0]`

Output

> '[{\'urlkey\': \'witi\', \'name\': \'Women in Technology\', \'id\': 10296}, {\'urlkey\': \'cross-mentoring-with-expert-ceo-business-owners\', \'name\': \'Cross Mentoring with expert CEO business owners\', \'id\': 15145}, {\'urlkey\': \'entrepreneurship\', \'name\': \'Entrepreneurship\', \'id\': 19882}, {\'urlkey\': \'womens-business-networking\', \'name\': "Women\'s Business Networking", \'id\': 21283}, {\'urlkey\': \'startup-businesses\', \'name\': \'Startup Businesses\', \'id\': 21681}, {\'urlkey\': \'lean-startup\', \'name\': \'Lean Startup\', \'id\': 38660}, {\'urlkey\': \'female-entrepreneurs\', \'name\': \'Female Entrepreneurs\', \'id\': 41905}, {\'urlkey\': \'founders\', \'name\': \'Founders\', \'id\': 46616}, {\'urlkey\': \'technology-startups\', \'name\': \'Technology Startups\', \'id\': 108403}, {\'urlkey\': \'ceo-2-ceo-coaching-mentoring-for-mutual-growth\', \'name\': \'CEO 2 CEO Coaching & Mentoring For Mutual Growth\', \'id\': 133122}, {\'urlkey\': \'cto\', \'name\': \'CTO\', \'id\': 141917}, {\'urlkey\': \'ceo\', \'name\': \'CEO\', \'id\': 141921}, {\'urlkey\': \'c-level-tech\', \'name\': \'C-Level Tech\', \'id\': 816562}, {\'urlkey\': \'ceos-founders\', \'name\': \'CEOs & Founders\', \'id\': 1379732}, {\'urlkey\': \'cio-cto\', \'name\': \'CIO / CTO\', \'id\': 1485582}]'`

Whereas the other cells look like so;

> [{'urlkey': 'opensource', 'name': 'Open Source', 'id': 563}, {'urlkey': 'ebizowners', 'name': 'E-Business Owners', 'id': 1330}, {'urlkey': 'softwaredev', 'name': 'Software Development', 'id': 3833}, {'urlkey': 'socialnetwork', 'name': 'Social Networking', 'id': 4422}, {'urlkey': 'web', 'name': 'Web Technology', 'id': 10209}, {'urlkey': 'technology', 'name': 'Technology', 'id': 10579}, {'urlkey': 'online-marketing', 'name': 'Online Marketing', 'id': 15585}, {'urlkey': 'digital-media', 'name': 'Digital Media', 'id': 17188}]

Could you help me with code to remove the \ (newline break I think) so all cells are similar.

Not sure if it is only for that first cell it may be in others but the rest look normal. However, code to remove for the whole column just in case would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I am curious to know how you've gotten to this point.

Comment: So this is topic data from a Meetup API call I made - this is part of a dataframe on meetup groups. Hope that gives a little more context

Comment: Care to produce a [mcve]? This can probably be prevented at the source.

Comment: Thank you for the guidelines I will refer to them when asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the content of the cell by evaluating it using the module `ast`:

```
import ast

>>> ast.literal_eval(s)

[{'id': 10296, 'name': 'Women in Technology', 'urlkey': 'witi'},
 {'id': 15145,
  'name': 'Cross Mentoring with expert CEO business owners',
  'urlkey': 'cross-mentoring-with-expert-ceo-business-owners'},
 {'id': 19882, 'name': 'Entrepreneurship', 'urlkey': 'entrepreneurship'},
 {'id': 21283,
  'name': "Women's Business Networking",
  'urlkey': 'womens-business-networking'},
 {'id': 21681, 'name': 'Startup Businesses', 'urlkey': 'startup-businesses'},
 {'id': 38660, 'name': 'Lean Startup', 'urlkey': 'lean-startup'},
 {'id': 41905,
  'name': 'Female Entrepreneurs',
  'urlkey': 'female-entrepreneurs'},
 {'id': 46616, 'name': 'Founders', 'urlkey': 'founders'},
 {'id': 108403,
  'name': 'Technology Startups',
  'urlkey': 'technology-startups'},
 {'id': 133122,
  'name': 'CEO 2 CEO Coaching & Mentoring For Mutual Growth',
  'urlkey': 'ceo-2-ceo-coaching-mentoring-for-mutual-growth'},
 {'id': 141917, 'name': 'CTO', 'urlkey': 'cto'},
 {'id': 141921, 'name': 'CEO', 'urlkey': 'ceo'},
 {'id': 816562, 'name': 'C-Level Tech', 'urlkey': 'c-level-tech'},
 {'id': 1379732, 'name': 'CEOs & Founders', 'urlkey': 'ceos-founders'},
 {'id': 1485582, 'name': 'CIO / CTO', 'urlkey': 'cio-cto'}]
```

If you removed the `"\'"` you wouldn't be able to return the list of dicts. For removing the `"\'"` just apply to the string `s.replace("\'","")`. I think that maybe the strings are different due to having different econdigs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking because I need the ' ' to split and label the list later according to name and urlkey. I will try this now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say df.apply(lambda x: x.replace("\'", '')) should do the job.

but for the more complex stuff,  pandas has the .replace method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html